# Oracle help java (ohj)

Tags: java

I was trying the Oracle help for Java. After all day, I have the `html` and files configuration and all worked fine. Except for one thing.

After modifications of the examples given by oracle, I have this class in my project,executed it and works fine.

```
package es.unileon.happycow;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

import oracle.help.Help;
import oracle.help.library.Book;
import oracle.help.library.helpset.HelpSet;

class HelpSystem2 {

    private static HelpSystem2 instance = null;

    private oracle.help.Help _helpObject;

    private HelpSystem2() {
        int i;
        Vector books = new Vector();

        boolean combineBooks = false;
        boolean useLabelInfo = true;
        try {
            URL fileURL = Init.class.getResource("/help/ohguide.hs");

            HelpSet aHelpSet = new HelpSet(fileURL);

            if (aHelpSet != null) {
                books.addElement(aHelpSet);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        setHelp(books, combineBooks, useLabelInfo);
    }

    public static HelpSystem2 getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new HelpSystem2();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private void setHelp(Vector books, boolean combineBooks, boolean useLabelInfo) {
        int i;

        Class htmlBrowserClass = null;

        try {
            htmlBrowserClass = Class.forName("oracle.help.htmlBrowser.ICEBrowser");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            htmlBrowserClass = null;
            System.err.println("Failed to load ICEBrowser");
        }
        _helpObject = new Help(htmlBrowserClass, combineBooks, useLabelInfo, true);

        if (books != null) {
            for (i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
                Book aBook = (Book) books.elementAt(i);
                _helpObject.addBook(aBook);
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        _helpObject.showNavigatorWindow();
    }
}

public class ChoiceDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelpSystem2.getInstance().start();
    }

}
```

It's a private class HelpSystem2 with methods and a public class with `main`.

After this code working, I copy the code of HelpSystem2 to a new class HelpSystem (exactly same code, all occurrences of HelpSystem2 changed to HelpSystem) and added this code in another class. All in the same project.

```
public JFrameController() {
    ...
    help();
}

private void help() {
    HelpSystem.getInstance().start();
}
```

But now is not working, the window appears, with the index of help, but the `html` is not displaying, only the empty window.

What's the difference?

---

The diff's output:

```
--- ChoiceDemo.java 2015-10-12 20:24:07.266411632 +0200
+++ HelpSystem.java 2015-10-12 20:25:54.469741168 +0200
@@ -8,13 +8,13 @@
 import oracle.help.library.Book;
 import oracle.help.library.helpset.HelpSet;

-class HelpSystem2 {
+public class HelpSystem {

-    private static HelpSystem2 instance = null;
+    private static HelpSystem instance = null;

     private oracle.help.Help _helpObject;

-    private HelpSystem2() {
+    private HelpSystem() {
     int i;
     Vector books = new Vector();

@@ -35,9 +35,9 @@
     setHelp(books, combineBooks, useLabelInfo);
     }

-    public static HelpSystem2 getInstance() {
+    public static HelpSystem getInstance() {
     if (instance == null) {
-            instance = new HelpSystem2();
+            instance = new HelpSystem();
     }
     return instance;
     }
@@ -66,12 +66,4 @@
     public void start() {
     _helpObject.showNavigatorWindow();
     }
-}
-
-public class ChoiceDemo {
-
-    public static void main(String[] args) {
-        HelpSystem2.getInstance().start();
-    }
-
-}
+}
\ No newline at end of file
```

And the structure of my project. The help's file remains the same for both, first code is ChoiceDemo.java, and the second is HelpSystem. In the second code, the flow of the application is Init instantiate JFrame, and JFrame instantiate JFrameController which have the `HelpSystem.getInstance().start();` in his constructor.

[image: structure of project]

Comment: Please give more information, I have no idea what the difference is. You could try doing a diff of the two folder structures with git?

Comment: I tried using HelpSystem instead of HelpSystem2 ( HelpSystem.getInstance().start(); ) in the ChoiceDemo.java, and still works. Calling it in the static main method of Init.java does not works. Same code, same function called, different sites. Makes no sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is the look and feel.

I used the Nimbus theme

```
try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error con el Look and feel");
    }
```

And ohj can't show the html. Commenting this, with the default or setting the oracle theme given by ohj, the code works wherever i call it.

My next problem is look for a new theme, those are too ugly... u.u